# Creating overall count of common equipment faults between two shifts when there are two identical column names. Using SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I am tracking equipment faults for A shift and B shift.
I have 2 out 3 queries working:
(1) count unique equipment faults for each shift (I have this working)
(2) display a count of the equipment faults that are common to both shifts (I can't get this to work). I think PIVOT will make this work but I'm struggling with how to take the two data results from (1) and use it here in (2) for the PIVOT.
(3) display a summary count of all unique equipment faults (I have this working).
I appreciate any help and apologize if my formatting is not correct for this (my first) post.

Here is the sample data:

```
   CREATE TABLE tbl_PrestartRdyScoreboard_test
    (   
    ndx int NOT NULL, 
    ShiftStart datetime null, 
    SheduledShift varchar(1) null, 
    PrestartMaintTeam varchar(1) null, 
    EmailCount smallint null,
    RdyStatus bit null,
    Equipment varchar(50) null, 
    CONSTRAINT ndx PRIMARY KEY (ndx)
    )

INSERT INTO tbl_PrestartRdyScoreboard_test
    (
    [ndx], [ShiftStart], [SheduledShift], [PrestartMaintTeam], [EmailCount], [RdyStatus], [Equipment]
     )
VALUES
    (1, '2023-10-10 06:15:00.000', 'A', 'A', 0, 0, 'Welder'),
    (2, '2023-10-10 17:30:00.000', 'B', 'B', 0, 0, 'Press'),
    (3, '2023-10-11 06:15:00.000', 'A', 'A', 0, 0, 'Drill'),
    (4, '2023-10-11 17:30:00.000', 'B', 'B', 0, 0, 'Drill'),
    (5, '2023-10-12 06:15:00.000', 'B', 'B', 0, 0, 'Drill'),
    (6, '2023-10-12 17:30:00.000', 'A', 'A', 0, 0, 'Saw')
    ;
```

The second query is the troublesome one because it shows 'Drill' as common in Shift A and Shift B instead of just indicating there is a count of 3 Drill incidents:

```
declare @start datetime = DATEADD(day, -30, getutcdate())
declare @end datetime = getutcdate()
--declare @SheduledShift1 VARCHAR(1)= 'D' -- days
--declare @SheduledShift2 VARCHAR(1)= 'A' -- afternoons
;

--Count Unique Equipment Events by Team. This is working
SELECT DISTINCT PrestartMaintTeam, Equipment, count(Equipment) as NumIncidents
FROM tbl_PrestartRdyScoreboard_test
WHERE ShiftStart > @start and ShiftStart < @end and PrestartMaintTeam <> 'U' and Equipment <> ''
GROUP BY PrestartMaintTeam, Equipment
order by PrestartMaintTeam, Equipment
;

--Count Unique Equipment Events by Team, only listing the ones that appear on both shifts. Not Working.
With 
t1 AS 
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT PrestartMaintTeam, Equipment, count(Equipment) as NumIncidents
    FROM tbl_PrestartRdyScoreboard_test
    WHERE ShiftStart > @start and ShiftStart < @end and PrestartMaintTeam = 'A' and Equipment <> ''
    GROUP BY PrestartMaintTeam, Equipment
),
t2 AS
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT PrestartMaintTeam, Equipment, count(Equipment) as NumIncidents
    FROM tbl_PrestartRdyScoreboard_test
    WHERE ShiftStart > @start and ShiftStart < @end and PrestartMaintTeam = 'B' and Equipment <> ''
    GROUP BY PrestartMaintTeam, Equipment
)
SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.Equipment = t2.Equipment
ORDER BY t1.Equipment
;

--Count of each Equipment Event across both teams. This is working.
SELECT COUNT(Equipment) as EquipCount, [Equipment]
FROM [tbl_PrestartRdyScoreboard_test]
where ShiftStart > @start and ShiftStart < @end and PrestartMaintTeam <> 'U' and Equipment <> ''
group by [Equipment]
order by [Equipment] asc
```

Here is the output:

| PrestartMaintTeam | Equipment | NumIncidents |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Drill | 1 |
| A | Saw | 1 |
| A | Welder | 1 |
| B | Drill | 2 |
| B | Press | 1 |

| PrestartMaintTeam | Equipment | NumIncidents | PrestartMaintTeam | PrestartMaintTeam | NumIncidents |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Drill | 1 | B | Drill | 2 |

| EquipCount | Equipment |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | Drill |
| 1 | Press |
| 1 | Saw |
| 1 | Welder |

I would like to add up the resulting common equipment faults so all that is displayed is:

| NumIncidents | Equipment |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | Drill |

When I tried to apply a PIVOT to the result sets of (1) where I count by Shift A and also Shift B, I get an error stating there are duplicate column names (Equipment).  The thing is, of course there are duplicate columns named Equipment because that is what I'm trying to find in common between both shifts.

Comment: You need to clarify your example data, and include the DML. Consider: `DECLARE @Table TABLE (Col1 INT, Col2 VARCHAR(30), ...); INSERT INTO @Table (Col1, Col2, ...) VALUES (1, 'aaa', ...), (2, 'bbb', ...) ...`

Comment: Thank you. I will work on this now and post asap.

Comment: I have updated with the DML

Comment: What is your expected results? Please show as a table.

Comment: you can create table using markdown like so: `|Col1|Col2|
|:---|:---|
|ID1|Val1|
|ID2|Val2|`

Comment: I updated the desired results table using Markdown, thank you.

Comment: I wish to thank everyone for helping me format my question properly.  I have now (I hope) used Markdown to show all tables properly.  I also apologize for overwriting whomever graciously formated my initial dataset for me (I went in a like a bulldozer and pasted my own DML script before I realized it had been done for me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over-thinking this. You don't need to mess around with making two resultsets and trying to pivot them.

Just use your final query that groups up only by `Equipment`, but add a `HAVING` clause which conditionally counts each `PrestartMaintTeam` to make sure they are both included.

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS NumIncidents,
  prs.Equipment
FROM tbl_PrestartRdyScoreboard_test prs
GROUP BY
  prs.Equipment
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN PrestartMaintTeam = 'A' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN PrestartMaintTeam = 'B' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/LqxVfxlx)

Note that `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` rarely make sense in the same query.

Comment: Thank you very much!  That is so simply laid out the way you have it, but I would never have gotten that on my own. I won't even say how long I struggled with this problem before posting my question.  This is an awesome community!